# Any way to use ssh to recover a Mac from spinning beach ball of death

Tags: macos, performance

On Linux, I can get to a ssh or Ctrl-Alt-F1 console and type in a command to restart the window manager.

Is there any equivalent for Mac Mountain Lion?

I tried ssh'ing to a frozen Mac, and I could kill individual processes, but I could not unstuck the machine. Running the command sudo reboot killed my ssh ability, but did not restart the machine.

Comment: This is probably doable, but it really depends on what's causing the beachballing. Does it happen with any predictability? If you can figure out which process is causing the issue, then killing it should work, unless it's something pretty low-level, or a hardware issue (I had a hard drive that would periodically drop connection, causing an unrecoverable beach ball).

Comment: If `sudo shutdown -r now` fails to kill off the processes and cause a reboot, you will probably need to pull the power or hold the power button pressed to recover.

Comment: Yep, I had to hold the power button down. "shutdown" only seemed to cut off ssh. The beach ball never stopped.

Comment: → Justin: Are you running MacOS X 10.8.3?

Comment: Yes, 10.8.3, latest MBP Retina.

Comment: Killing the Dock process frequently resolves beach balls for me, and can almost always be done over SSH, even when it can't be done locally. It's harmless even if it doesn't work; Dock will just restart.

Comment: I've sent the log files to apple support. What I've noticed is: 1. No common pattern to crashes. 2. I've had spinning beach ball, locked arrow cursor, and now, the blue blank screen when the display wakes up! And the crashes are getting more frequent. I think the video card is overheating!

Answer (score 4):

To reply to your question: no there isn't such a function accessible
at the window manager level.
It is a good suggestion to forward to [Apple MacOS X feedback](https://www.apple.com/feedback/macosx.html)

Is your Mac still up?

Try:

```
ping IP_of_my_mac
```

Can you access it with `ssh`?

Can you provide us a copy of the output of a:

```
top -o cpu
```

and:

```
tail -20 /var/log/system.log
```

If the problem appears once more, could you try to kill the loginwindow
like this:
    connect on your mad Mac with ssh

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/kill `ps ax | grep '[/]loginwindow' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

This uggly command:

```
ps ax | grep '[/]loginwindow' | awk '{print $1}'
```

is a trick to give you the process ID of the loginwindow process with no
risk to kill the wrong guy.
I'm not sure this will be enough to force a total free and reset of the GPU.
*Please tell me if this doesn't work so I could remove a useless and dangerous workaround.*

Comment: Top didn't show anything. Here are some log messages: 5/8/13 10:01:16.000 AM kernel[0]: IOVendorGLContext::ReportGPURestart 
5/8/13 10:01:16.000 AM kernel[0]: NVDA(OpenGL): Channel exception! exception type = 0xd = GR: SW Notify Error, 5/8/13 10:19:31.913 AM mdworker[62359]: Unable to talk to lsboxd

Comment: It looks like you have a GPU hardware of driver problem. I advise you to make copies of these error messages and bring them to an AppleStore.

Comment: Now, no spinning beachball, but 2 more crashes: May 10 00:07:58 JustinMbp.local coreservicesd[29]: SendFlattenedData, got error #268435460 (ipc/send) timed out from ::mach_msg(), sending notification kLSNotifyApplicationDeath to notificationID=237
May 10 00:08:08 JustinMbp kernel[0]: NVDA(OpenGL): Channel timeout!
May 10 00:08:15 JustinMbp.local sshd[4051]: Accepted keyboard-interactive/pam for justin from 192.168.1.69 port 42150 ssh2
May 10 00:08:15 JustinMbp.local sshd[4051]: USER_PROCESS: 4054 ttys017
May 10 00:08:28 JustinMbp kernel[0]: NVDA(OpenGL): Channel timeout!

Comment: May 10 00:08:36 JustinMbp.local fseventsd[43]: SLOWDOWN: client 0x7fb57401a800 (pid 2254) sleeping due to too many errors (num usleeps 11)

Comment: Running the last command to kill the login proces results in the plain cursor turning into a spinning beach ball.

Comment: If you still have an `ssh` access, could you get the output of the following command:

`ps aelx | egrep '[/]loginwindow|[ ]PID'`

Comment: → Justin: your loginwindow wasn't able to reset your graphical card (through the Kernel extension). The `Channel timeout` means your motherboard can't get a reply of the graphical card in a normal delay.
I repeat here my 1st approcach suggestion:
make copies of your `kernel[0]: NVDA(…` error messages and bring the whole to an AppleStore.

Answer (score 1):

I use this in a shell script called `restart-graphical.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh

sudo killall -HUP WindowServer

exit 0
```

This will NOT give you a chance to save anything.

Note that I *have* run into a situation where nothing will help except the power plug. This is often when a USB or FireWire device has caused an incurable hang.

Comment: I'm not sure what advantage this would be over the power switch? Avoid any disk errors maybe?

Comment: I tried this and the spinning beach ball disappeared, but nothing else happened.

Comment: The advantage is that you can try it in situations when you don't have access to the power switch. And if you can get to the login screen (which is what should happen when you run it) you may be able to do a clean reboot.

Comment: No login screen appeared. I had to use the power switch.